# How to wire hypersonic db as a spring batch configuration for persisting jobs in java

Tags: spring-batch, spring-annotations

I would like to use Hypersonic in memory DB to persist jobs as I need to run the same job multiple times on separate threads. The SimpleJobRepository can not be used as I run into Optimistic locking issue.

Does any one has a sample java configuration file and how to wire the hypersonic for spring batch job in java with annotation?

Comment: Share your configuration.  I believe there are a couple things that need to be set for it to work well in a multithreaded environment.